# Phalcon PHP in RunCloud

Tags: php, phalcon

To install Phalcon PHP on servers managed by RunCloud, something special to do as RunCloud installs multiple versions of PHP? How to install Phalcon for an X version of PHP? Thanks.

I'm having some difficulty understanding the logic for this type of installation.

Comment: I haven't used RunCloud, but I suppose that Phalcon must be installed for every version that you are going to use: for 7.0/7.2 you could install Phalcon 3.4.5, for 7.4, Phalcon 4.1.3 (plus PSR extension) and for 8.0+, Phalcon 5.x.